# Comparando um elemento do array com uma string

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso criar uma função que receba um *array* e compare com uma *string*, fora do *array*, retornando `true` se, e somente se, existir a ocorrência de pelo menos duas vezes da *string* fora do *array*. A saída deve ser semelhante a isso:

```
Str2(["a", "b", "a", "c"], "c");
//=> "false"

Str2(["a", "b", "a", "c"], "a");
//=> "true"
```

A função abaixo, deveria fazer isso, mas sempre retorna false".

```
var Str2 = function(strs, str){
    var i, a = 0;

    for(i=0; strs.length; i++){
        if (str == strs[i] ) {
            a = a + 1;
            if (a > 1) {return "true";}
            else {return "false";}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que na tua lógica o `return false` devia estar no final do loop, pois só aí vais saber que não há repetições.

Mas o teu problema é outro, é que tens esse loop com erros:

#1 - Deve ser `i < strs.length;` e não somente `; length;`.
#2 - A primeira iteração vai ter o `i` com valor `1` e isso dá false em `i > 1)` então vai para o `else`...

Corrigido seria:

```
var Str2 = function (strs, str) {
    var i, a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        if (str == strs[i]) {
            a++;
            if (a > 1) return "true";
        }
    }
    return "false";
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xwajvrm/1/

Repara ainda noutro possível problema, é que estás a retornar *Strings* e não *Booleanos*. Nota que `"false"` e `false` não é a mesma coisa...

Tendo dito isto sobre o teu código eu sugiro usares o `.filter()` que faz exatamente o que queres. Assim:

```
var Str2 = function(strs, str){
    return strs.filter(function(el){
        return el == str;
    }).length > 1;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xwajvrm/

Comment: Corrigi a resposta pois expliquei certo na primeira linha mas tinha deixado errado no código...

Answer (score 4):

É só tirar o `false`de dentro do laço. Se ele chegar na contagem de 2, ele pode encerrar a execução retornando `true`. Mas se ele não atingir essa condição, ele tem que ficar tentando até o fim, ele não pode retornar `false` dentro do laço. Se ele sair do laço, significa que a contagem nunca atingir 2, então pode retornar `false`.

```js
let str2 = function(strs, str) {    
    var a = 0; 
    for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {        
        if (str == strs[i]) {
            a++;                       
            if (a > 1) return "true";
        }
    }
    return 'false';
}
console.log(str2(["a", "b", "a", "c"], "c"));
console.log(str2(["a", "b", "a", "c"], "a"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/IsRepeated.js).

Comment: sábado a noite se ta roubando minhas resposta ;)

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso. Quando é maior que 1, na saída aparece "true", mas quando a string aparece uma única vez, não retorna false.

Comment: @VanessaRibeiro Do jeito que eu fiz aparece.

Comment: Obrigada! Já resolvi...

Comment: @VanessaRibeiro Eu sei que o Sergio vai acertar mas a dele está errado. Pelo menos dentro do método que você está usando.

Comment: Entendi, é que na realidade acabou faltando um sinal de menor que limita o laço, como o Sérgio sugeriu...

Comment: @VanessaRibeiro é tinha mas esse erro que eu não percebi. Agora está certo.

Answer (score 3):

O problema ai é que dentro da primeira execução ele verifica:

```
a > 1 ?
```

Mas na primeira execução nunca vai ser maior que 1, logo como você coloca o else. Ele sempre cai no else. O certo é verificar isso depois.

Segue exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/dk86foxb/

```
var Str2 = function(strs, str){    
    var i, a = 0;   
    for(i=0; i < strs.length; i++){        
        if (str == strs[i] ) {
            a = a + 1;                       
        }
        if (a > 1) {
            return "true";
        } 
    }
    return 'false';
}
```